# Using float and long data types in java

Tags: java

Why do most programmers avoid using the **float** and **long** data types in their video tutorials?
Is it only to avoid the "0000f" and "0000L" notation?

Comment: what do you mean ? longs are useful if you need a long, which is not every day.

Comment: Not sure where you got that impression. Can you post some relevant links to articles which suggest this ?

Comment: what is the need to use these two? In tutorials it is easy to use int and double is just a standard used to store decimal numbers. I do not see any other reason and no need to worry about it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I avoid `float` has it has poor precision.  I would rather use `double` (or long with fixed precision or if I have to BigDecimal).

I suspect `long` is not often used as `int` is usually enough and many Java APIs only accept `int` values. e.g. array sizes and Collection/Map size() must be `int`.

Answer (score 1):

And why should they use them? Perhaps the one reason is to avoid writing a letter indicating that the float/long type is used.

However if you don't need any special precision, why use `double` instead of `float` or `long` instead of `int`?

Comment: especially since `double` has more precision than `float`. One could say "double" the precision.